# Randomize the radius of a curve

Tags: modeling, scripting, add-on, bezier-curves

I have a curve object that includes several curves. I want to randomize the radius of each separate curve piece. Each point on the curve piece should have the same radius, but each piece has a different random radius.

Some control is necessary. I want to be able to set a minimum and maximum number for the radius.

Is there any existing methods or addons to do this? How about with python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it manually, in edit mode use <kbd>L</kbd> to select linked points and adjust the radius property which will be applied to all selected points. The radius property can be found in the properties sidebar <kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

Or you can automate it with python. A curve object can have multiple [`splines`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Spline.html), each spline then has multiple points. Note that bezier curves and nurbs curves use different property names for the points. For bezier curves it is `bezier_points` while nurbs curves use `points`.

```
import bpy
import random

c_obj = bpy.data.objects['BezierCurve']

for s in c_obj.data.splines:
    spl_rad = random.random()
    # change to s.points for nurbs curves
    for p in s.bezier_points:
        p.radius = spl_rad
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single curve object that includes several curves, changing the *Bevel Depth* in the *Geometry* panel will change the radius of **all curves** in your object...

One way to do what you want, is to create several curve objects and to join them in a same group named '**curve_group**' (this name is used in the following script).

Running the following python script will change the depth randomly from 0.01 to 0.1 :

```
import bpy
from random import uniform
for obj in bpy.data.groups['curve_group'].objects:
    obj.data.bevel_depth=uniform(0.01, 0.1)
    obj.data.bevel_resolution=5
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! It looks like this sets the Bevel Radius for several curve objects. I need to set the radius of control points of multiple splines within the same curve object.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to do this procedurally, you can use Sverchok Add-On to quickly access those joined curves, get the points of each curve, regenerate them as NEW Curves all with random radius.

[image: curve with random radius]

If you want to keep the original single Curve object with multiple Spline, you can really use Python and directly targetting the Bezier Point Radius. Visually shown here using Sverchok:

[image: visual node]

Thanks to SV Dev Zeff also we have this way to do it:
[image: sverchok on the fly script node]

Comment: Alternatively you can also use bpy I think:
import bpy

bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[0].bezier_points[0].radius = 6
bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve'].splines[2].bezier_points[0].radius = 3